# Linked Server Insert Permission

Tags: sql-server-2014, linked-server

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'object_name', database 'database_2', schema 'dbo'.
```

Above is the error. I have a linked server set up (set up in prod which links to test server). I want to insert a data from prod to test. `INSERT` statement is working on database 1 but error above occurs on database 2. Is there a way to check the permissions of local user (prod) to linked server objects (test)? Where should I check for the missing set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was in a hurry to ask it since it was urgent. For those who will encounter it, this may help:

Check the user that was used in the linked server. That permission in the linked server (in my case, on the test) should be set up properly.

In my case, it has no access on database_2.